# Not receiving error for field in JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

i have created a dummy database of arrays this is

```
 const movies =   {
    _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471816",
    title: "Die Hard",
    genre: { _id: "5b21ca3eeb7f6fbccd471818", name: "Action" },
    numberInStock: 5,
    dailyRentalRate: 2.5
    },
```

there is no `liked :true` in movies array but when I map it I added movie.liked its not giving me any error why?

```
{this.state.movies.map((movie) => (
<tr key={movie.id}>
<td>{movie.title}</td>
<td>{movie.genre.name}</td>
<td>{movie.numberInStock}</td>
<td>{movie.dailyRentalRate}</td>
```

`<td> <Like liked={movie.liked} onClick={() =>this.handleLike(movie)}/> </td>`

```
 <td
    onClick={() => this.handleDelete(movie.id)}
    className="btn btn-danger btn-outline-warning btn-sm active "
    >
    Remove
    </td>
    </tr>

))}
```

Comment: `movie.liked` will be undefined, so it doesn't really matter

Comment: `movie.liked` resolves `undefined`, so you're actually passing `liked={undefined}` into the props. If it used as a boolean, the result would be `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using Typescript, it would catch this and show an error.

With plain JS though, fields that have not been defined, like `movie.liked`, will just resolve to `undefined` when accessed.

Then `undefined` is passed in as a prop, which then will act like `false` if you use it later in that component.